# Stuck on making a RSS feed discord bot

Tags: python, discord, rss

I'm new to this so please cut me some slack. I'm trying to get RSS feed news into my Discord guild but I hit a bump. I'm using import request to get the feed but I don't know how to have the bot output it in my channel. This is what I have in my bot file to run my bot:

```
import hikari

bot = hikari.GatewayBot(token='')



bot.run()
```

and this is what I have in another file to get the feed:

```
import requests

x = requests.get('http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/topstories/')

print(x.text)
```

I'm just trying to combine this together or maybe have another way introduced to me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to output to a specific channel, you need something like this:

```
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel ID here)
      await channel.send(x.link)
```

As for the `x.link` part, that comes with feedparser, which you can get with `import feedparser`. You would then get the feed with the following:

```
x = feedparser.parse('rss link here')
```

This is what I've been using so far, I hope it's of some help.